# How to call Update function's code by button click

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, long-press

How can I call the codes, inside the `Update` function using a `public` method?

What I need to archive is, calling `Update` using another function.

So that `Update` triggers using that other method.

One more thing, code should run only when a button long press.

Many Thanks four help

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 1500f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 15f;

    public WheelJoint2D backWheel;
    public WheelJoint2D frontWheel;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    private float movement = 0f;
    private float rotation = 0f;



    void Update()
    {

        rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (movement == 0f)
        {
            backWheel.useMotor = false;
            frontWheel.useMotor = false;
        }
        else
        {

            backWheel.useMotor = true;
            frontWheel.useMotor = true;

            JointMotor2D motor = new JointMotor2D { motorSpeed = movement, maxMotorTorque = 10000 };
            backWheel.motor = motor;
            frontWheel.motor = motor;


        }

        rb.AddTorque(-rotation * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    //public void Rotate()
    //{
    //    rotate = true;
    //    print("aa");
    //}
    //public void Move()
    //{
    //    rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    //    movement = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are actually two questions.

#### 1. A long press button

The Unity `UI.Button` hasn't per se a method for a long press but you can use the [IPointerXHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) interfaces for implementing that on your own:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

// RequireComponent makes sure there is Button on the GameObject
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class LongPressButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        ResetButton();
    }

    // set the long press duration in the editor (in seconds)
    public float LongPressDuration = 0.5f;

    // Here you reference method just like in onClick

    public UnityEvent onLongPress;

    private float _timer;
    private bool _isPressed;
    private bool _pressInvoked;

    private void Update()
    {
        // prevent multiple calls if button stays pressed
        if (_pressInvoked) return;

        // if button is not pressed do nothing
        if (!_isPressed) return;

        // reduce the timer by the time passed since last frame
        _timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        // if timeout not reached do nothing
        if (!(_timer <= 0)) return;

        // Invoke the onLongPress event -> call all referenced callback methods
        onLongPress.Invoke();
        _pressInvoked = true;
    }

    // reset all flags and timer
    private void ResetButton()
    {
        _isPressed = false;
        _timer = LongPressDuration;
        _pressInvoked = false;
    }


    /* IPointer Callbacks */    

    // enable the timer
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    // reset if button is released before timeout
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ResetButton()
    }

    // reset if cursor leaves button before timeout
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ResetButton();
    }
}
```

This script has to be placed next to the `Button` component.

You don't reference the callback method(s) in the `Button`'s
`onClick` but instead in this `LongPressButton`'s `onLongPress`

and don't forget to adjust `LongPressDuration` also in the inspector.

Example

[image]

#### 2. Calling `CarController`'s `Update`

I don't know why you want this (I guess you disabled the component but want to call `Update` anyway)

**Solution A**

In order to be able to reference that  method in the Inspector there are a few options:

1. Simply make your `Update` method `public`

   ```c#
   public void Update()
   {
       rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       movement = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;
   }
   ```
2. wrap the content of `Update` in another `public` method and use that one instead:

   ```c#
   private void Update()
   {
       DoUpdateStuff();
   }

   public void DoUpdateStuff()
   {
       rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       movement = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;
   }
   ```
3. the other way round (how you requested it) - call `Update` from another `public` method:

   ```c#
   private void Update()
   {
       rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       movement = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;
   }

   public void DoUpdateStuff()
   {
       Update();
   }
   ```

So all that's left is referencing the `CarController`'s `Update` or `DoUpdateStuff` method in the `LongPressButton`'s `onLongPress` event.

---

**Solution B**

Alternatively you could add that callback directly on runtime without referencing anything nor making the callback method `public` so you could directly use `private void Update` without a wrapper method.

**Drawback**: For this method you somehow have to get the reference to that `LongPressButton` in your `CarController` script instead

```c#
public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Somehow get the reference for this either by referencing it or finding it on runtime etc
    // I will asume this is already set
    public LongPressButton longPressButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // make sure listener is only added once
        longPressButton.onLongPress.RemoveListener(Update);

        longPressButton.onLongPress.AddListener(Update);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * speed;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // clean up the listener
        longPressButton.onLongPress.RemoveListener(Update);
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your descriptive reply. What I did was change my script to following and added Event Trigger component. Then call the public functions accordingly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarMve : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool move = false;
    bool moveR = false;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float speed = 20f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 2f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (move == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 100f, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
        if (moveR == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right *- speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 100f, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }

    /* Will be used on the UI Button */
    public void MoveCar(bool _move)
    {
        move = _move;
    }
    public void MoveCarR(bool _moveR)
    {
        moveR = _moveR;
    }

}
```

[image]